# How to solve the error occuring to my pytorch implementation of Exposure detection?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, torch, torchvision

I am trying to create a code for correcting for wrong exposure in images. I have a dataset_creation where I am creating the dataset for pairing the dataset. I am taking one input image and then finding the corresponding target image and then pair them. Then I am using CNN to train a model using both of these images.

Dataset_creation code:

```
#importing necessary libraries
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from PIL import Image
import os

#defining a class for pairing the dataset

class ImagePairDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, input_dir, target_dir, transform=None):
        self.input_dir = input_dir
        self.target_dir = target_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_name_list = self.target_list()  
        self.input_filenames = os.listdir(input_dir)
        self.target_filenames = os.listdir(target_dir)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.input_filenames)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        train_img_name = self.input_filenames[index].split("-")[0]
        train_img = Image.open(os.path.join(self.input_dir, self.input_filenames[index]))
        for i in range(len(self.target_name_list)):
            if train_img_name == self.target_name_list[i]:
                target_img = Image.open(os.path.join(self.target_dir, self.target_filenames[i]))
                break
        if self.transform:
            train_img = self.transform(train_img)
            target_img = self.transform(target_img)
        return train_img, target_img[0]

    def target_list(self):
        target_name_list = []
        target_names = os.listdir(self.target_dir)
        for target_name in target_names:
            target_name = target_name.split("-")[0]
            target_name_list.append(target_name)
        return target_name_list


#directories for input and target
input_dir = 'training/INPUT_IMAGES'
target_dir = 'training/GT_IMAGES'
```

Training code :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torchvision.models import densenet121
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader , random_split
from Dataset_creation import ImagePairDataset
import os

device = torch.device("cuda")
torch.cuda.get_device_name()

image_size = 224
model = densenet121(pretrained = True)
model.to(device)

num_features = model.classifier.in_features
model.classifier = nn.Linear(num_features , 1)
model.to(device)

criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimiser = optim.Adam(model.parameters() , lr = 0.001)

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((image_size,image_size)),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

input_dir = 'training\INPUT_IMAGES'
target_dir = 'training\GT_IMAGES'

dataset = ImagePairDataset(input_dir , target_dir , transform = transform)

train_size = int(0.6*len(dataset))
val_size = int(0.2*len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - (train_size + val_size)

train_dataset , val_dataset , test_dataset = random_split(dataset , [train_size , val_size , test_size])

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset,batch_size = 16 , shuffle = True)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset,batch_size = 16)
test_dataset = DataLoader(test_dataset , batch_size = 16)

num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0
    model.train()
    
    for inputs,targets in train_dataloader:
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        targets = targets.to(device)
        optimiser.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs,targets.unsqueeze(1).float())
        
        loss.backward()
        optimiser.step()
        
        running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)

    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_dataloader.dataset)
    print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}")
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Here I am getting an error :

Exception has occurred: ValueError
Target size (torch.Size([16, 1, 224, 224])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([16, 1]))
File "Y:\Personal Projects\Exposure_detection\Exp_detection.py", line 54, in 
loss = criterion(outputs,targets.unsqueeze(1).float())
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([16, 1, 224, 224])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([16, 1]))

Can someone please help me find a solution for this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a design issue, your  code shows that you are using a DenseNet model, if memory serves,  U-Net, Pix2Pix, or CycleGAN are generally more appropriate, and are designed to output images of the same size as the input.